# PMI of the elements of two lists

Tags: python, similarity

I would like to calculate the pointwise-mutual information scores of the elements of two lists.
Let's say we have

```
ListA = "Hi there, This is only a test message. Please enjoy the weather in the park."
ListB = "work, bank, tree, weather, sun"
```

How can I then calculate the PMI scores of all pairs (work, Hi), (work, there), (work, This) .... (sun, park).

It worked for me to calculate the PMIs of bigrams of one list:

```
def pmi(word1, word2, unigram_freq, bigram_freq, unigram_freq_values, bigram_freq_values, output_name):
    prob_word1 = unigram_freq[word1] / float(sum(unigram_freq_values))
    prob_word2 = unigram_freq[word2] / float(sum(unigram_freq_values))
    prob_word1_word2 = bigram_freq / float(sum(bigram_freq_values))
    pmi =  math.log(prob_word1_word2/float(prob_word1*prob_word2),2)

unigrams = nltk.FreqDist(ListA)
bigrams = ngrams(ListA,2)

n1_freq = nltk.FreqDist(unigrams)
n2_freq = nltk.FreqDist(bigrams)

output_pmi = "test.txt"
for bigram, freq in n2_freq.most_common(1000):
    w1 = bigram[0]
    w2 = bigram[1]
    unigram_freq_val = n1_freq.values()
    bigram_freq_val = n2_freq.values()
    pmi(w1, w2, unigrams, freq, unigram_freq_val, bigram_freq_val, output_pmi)
```

I got stuck to the problem calculating the PMI of bigrams from ListA and ListB. I'd really appreciate it if anybody could help me. Thanks a lot!

(The two lists are, of course, minimal examples of how my task look like.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find all the combinations of the two lists:

```
import itertools

ListA = "Hi there, This is only a test message. Please enjoy the weather in the park."
ListB = "work, bank, tree, weather, sun"
WordsA = ListA.split()
WordsB = ListB.split()
#print(WordsA, "\n\n", WordsB)              #This is to show what the new lists are
c = list(itertools.product(WordsA, WordsB))
print(c)
```

Comment: But how can I, afterwards, calculate the PMI of this combination? It's this part which is still unclear to me.

Comment: Yes, I also had trouble thinking of that. Can you give me a description of PMI as I have (sort of) forgotten what that is. I have done what I can for now but I may be able to come up with a full solution to your problem if you can explain it. Also, if you think I have helped (or am trying to help) then please +1 my code as it really helps. Thanks!